# Worst case circuit analysis question

Tags: ldo

[image]

How to start with worst case circuit analysis (performance analysis) of a power supply circuit which includes LDO , resistors , capacitors , inductors. Part data base development is done. I need to start with analysis. Help regarding from where to start with analysis in a schematic

Comment: You start with a list of requirements that need to be met.

Comment: I see no inductors...

Answer (score 1):

Once you have your requirements (like @Andyaka points out as the first step) you can do 2 things. A paper or computational analysis based on the min and max limits in the datasheet, and a worst-case or Monte-Carlo simulation based on the manufacturer's model:

[LP5912 SPICE models](http://www.ti.com/product/LP5912/toolssoftware)

The model will be typical, so it will not give you worst case over process or temperature but it can help you spot problems due to external component variations. Be sure to take the ceramic capacitor voltage and temperature derating into account.  If you can, get the SPICE model for your capacitors from the manufacturer.  Murata has some good models for many of their caps.

Be sure to look at transient response and phase margin over load, as LDOs can have phase margin problems depending on output capacitance and load current level.

Startup, shutdown, enable, PSRR and noise performance are also potential things to look out for, again based on your requirements.

Thermal margin is also important, so power dissipation and layout will be key there.